# Can't get the properties of an instance

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to run this simple code while learning how to use .prototype.
I put `p = new Particle();` expecting to be able to se p in the console.
But it's undefined. I can't see the properties of p as I expected.

```
function Particle(){
  this.x = 100
  this.y = 99
  this.show = function(){
    point(this.x, this.y);
  }
}

var p;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 300);
  p = new Particle();
}
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to call `setup()`?

Comment: do you get an error? what is `point`?

Comment: I don't get an error. If I write p = new Particle(); in the console instead of in the code I get p with its list of properties. But if I include p = new Partice(); in the code in the setup function (i declared var p; as global to see it) I see p as undefined in the console.

Comment: here is point
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/point

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and don't see error anymore:

```
function Particle(){
      this.x = 100
      this.y = 99
      this.show = function(){
        point(this.x, this.y);
      }
    }
    
    var p;
    
    function setup() {
      p = new Particle();
    }
    
    setup();
    console.log(p)
```